# How can I solve this "Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate" error?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, uitextfield

I've been reported this error since I've included this lines in my code...

```
TextField("\(cellText)", text: Binding<String>(get: {
                        self.useB ? self.userCode : self.code
                    }, set: {
                        if self.useB == true {
                            self.userCode = ""
                        } else {
                            self.code = ""
                        }
                    }))
```

Can anybody help me understanding what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The `set:` signature requires parameter to be specified or used inside, it cannot be just omited

Here is fixed variant (for that of provided snapshot)

```
TextField("\(cellText)", text: Binding<String>(get: {
                        self.useB ? self.userCode : self.code
                    }, set: { _ in              // << if not used, specify it !!
                        if self.useB == true {
                            self.userCode = ""
                        } else {
                            self.code = ""
                        }
                    }))
```